# How can I edit the HTML output of sidebar in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Alright so i am trying to change the HTML output for wordpress sidebars.

I tried using: register_sidebar(); and use after/before title and after/before widget.

The above does work to some extent however the way that the HTML output is now it's missing the body of the widget and i would like to edit it and add a div wrapping the body of the widget.

Right now its.

```
 <div class="beforewidget">
      <div class="title">
      </div>

      // content of the widget
 </div>
```

I want to change it so the content of the widget would be wrapped with div as well.

Here is my register_sidebar()

```
 $args = array(
'name'          => __( 'Normal Sidebar', 'theme_text_domain' ),
'id'            => '3',
'description'   => 'Normal Sidebar',
    'class'         => '',
'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-body">',
'after_widget'  => '</div>',
'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title">',
'after_title'   => '</div>' );
register_sidebar( $args );
```

Which file do I need to edit?

Comment: please post your register_sidebar() function

Comment: here we go. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Why would this question be down voted ? Did i break any rules ? Its a good question and there isn't much documentation for a solution either. i know i made a mistake with not including my register_sidebar but its was corrected.

Comment: Someone down voted it because you had not provided enough information I'm guessing, wasn't me though. This was before you had posted the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $args = array(
'name'          => __( 'Normal Sidebar', 'theme_text_domain' ),
'id'            => '3',
'description'   => 'Normal Sidebar',
'class'         => '',
'before_widget' => '</div><div class="widget-body">',
'after_widget'  => '</div>',
'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title">',
'after_title'   => '' );
```

try that

Comment: I thought of doing that however if there is no title i have a closing div laying around. Also yours is a bit wrong if i were going this way i would add the widget body at the after_title and the closing at after_widget

Comment: did a little Googleing and seems you can't do what you are wanting to do without modifying Wordpress core. Its intended that theme developers use lists instead of divs for compatability. You may be able to extend the WP class that creates the widgets and override it. I've done it before regarding the menu generation, but I don't know where to begin in this case and I don't have a WP install to test on.

Comment: Cryptic thanks for the help. i will try finding how to edit the core to do it.
 Thanks very much for Help

Comment: You really don't want to edit the core you want to extend it. Because otherwise you will lose any modifications when you do a WP update. Find the relevant class that handles widget generation, and then make a class in your functions.php file in theme folder to extend that class and customize what the relevant method is doing to the widgets.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example found this while looking up documentation for you. It's basically the same thing. Find copy the method from WP_Widget class from your core files. Then make a new class with the same method, where the class...

Comment: extends WP_Widget, you then modify the new method to output in the way you want. Keep all code bits intact otherwise, just change your order and/or HTML, you don't want to remove something important. The method you want to apply the class extending to is public function widget( $args, $instance )

Comment: @Neta Meta: I just want to point out that classes **widget-body** and **widget-title** can be replaced by custom classes of your own.